# Information from two layers map.on method

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Is there a way to request information through the map.on method about different veclayers? If I have two JSON veclayers, for example veclayer1 and veclayer2, could I format the information obtained from veclayer1 and another from veclayer2? Something in the way:

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
var feature = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    });

if (layer === veclayer1) {
...
} else if (layer === veclayer2) {
...
}
}
```

I tried Mike's answer (the first and the second):

```
var map= new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view:view,
    layers: [osm, vectorLayer, catchs],
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      zoom: false,
      attribution: false,
      rotate: false,
    }),
});
map.on('click', function (evt) {
    $('#infos').show();
    document.getElementById("contINFO").innerHTML = '<h3>click on layer</h3>';

    /*var feature = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    });*/
    
    var layer;
    var feature = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature, featureLayer) {
        layer = featureLayer;
        return feature;
    });
    
    if(layer === catchs){
        let html = "", cod= "", art= "", date= ""; 
        for (i=0; i<feature.length; i++){('')
            if(feature[i].get('cod') != cod){
                art= ""; date= ""; 
                cod= feature[i].get('cod');
                html+="<div class='txt><i class='fas fa-water'></i> " + cod + "</div>";
            }
            if(feature[i].get('art') != art){
                date= "";
                art = feature[i].get('art');
                html+="<div class='txtart'><i class='fas fa-ship'></i> Art&nbsp;" + art + "</div>";
            }
            if(feature[i].get('date') != date){
                
                date = feature[i].get('date');
                html+="<div class='txtdate'><i class='far fa-calendar-alt'></i>&nbsp;" + date + "</div>";
            }
                    
            html+="<div class='tabtxt'><div class='txtrow'><div class='txtcell'><div class='textcod'>" + feature[i].get('cod2') + "</div></div><div class='txtcell'><div class='textcod'>" + feature[i].get('kg') + "&nbsp;kg&nbsp;-</div></div><div class='txtcell'><div class='textcod'>&nbsp;" + feature[i].get('operation') + "</div></div></div></div>";
            
            document.getElementById("contINFO").innerHTML = html;
        }
    }else if(layer === vectorLayer){
            var records = document.getElementById('contINFO');
            records.innerHTML = '';
            var html = '';
            for (i=0; i<features.length; i++){
                $('#infos').show();
                if(features[i].get('name') != null){
                    records.innerHTML += '<div id="aphia" class="aphia">' + features[i].get('name') + '</div>'
                }else{
                    records.innerHTML += '';
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But in both it only brings me back:

```
Click on layer
```

Comment: Look at the corrected answer. It should be `forEachFeatureAtPixel` method, not `getFeaturesAtPixel`.

Comment: oh, that's right !, an error when writing the code. I corrected it with map.forEachFeatureAtPixel, but I`m getting no response. actually if I put an alert in each condition I get the alert, but not the response with the html structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a variable which has scope outside the callback, or return the layer as well as the feature from the callback, for example

```
var layer;
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature, featureLayer) {
        layer = featureLayer;
        return feature;
    });
if (layer === veclayer1) {
...
} else if (layer === veclayer2) {
...
}
```

or

```
var result = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature, layer) {
        return {feature, layer};
    });
var feature = result.feature;
var layer = result.layer;
if (layer === veclayer1) {
...
} else if (layer === veclayer2) {
...
}
```

Comment: I saw the callback and assumed it was `forEachFeatureAtPixel`.  There is no callback with `getFeaturesAtPixel`, if one is specified it will be ignored.  The only way to access the layer is using `forEachFeatureAtPixel`.

Comment: Ok thanks Mike, I'll try to find a solution

Comment: Sorry, I put getFeaturesAtPixel instead of forEachFeatureAtPixel, I corrected it but I don't get a response. I put an alert in each condition, I receive the alert but I don't get a result, the javascript must be wrong.

Comment: Working example https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layers-vlx3p

Comment: If it works for me with that method, if I click on layer1 it will get the information from layer1 and layer2 the same. The problem I have is that I cannot do the for loop to read the different values. For example the layer1 (points) I click on a point that has a code and several dates, it only takes me a date.
I want to get:
```**COD:** 254756
**Date:** 2021-09-07
           2021-09-12
... ```

Comment: To display all the properties of a feature you could use `JSON.stringify(Object.entries(feature.getProperties()).filter(function (entry) {return entry[0] !== "geometry";}))`

Comment: Is there an example that I can see? thanks Mike

Comment: I have updated https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layers-vlx3p